# What Disney animated film was the first to feature blood?

Tags: first-appearance, disney

Yesterday, my buddies and I were watching the movie *UP*, and in the scene where Mr. Frederickson hits the worker for moving his mailbox, the worker moves his hand to reveal blood on his head.

One of my friends then commented saying "I think this is the first Disney movie to have blood.", but I waved him off, sure there was another one older than that that has featured blood.

Is there? Or have I gone crazy?

Comment: You may want to specify if you mean blood in general, or in the context of violence. But judging from a quick google search, even several of the Pixar movies seem to "contain" blood. Finding Nemo for example, where Dory gets a nosebleed. And i bet there were several others before "Up".

Comment: What was the first movie to have "blood" from a violent action of some sort? I know Disney started out movies with not that much "graphic violence"

Comment: I would be surprised if it were.  Disney has a big back catalog of live action movies too.

Comment: You wasted a perfectly good opportunity for a "First Blood" pun, i.e., "Disney's First Blood" or something like that. :-(

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark Full-length, or do short ones count as well?

Comment: @Walt any count

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seeing that you're after short ones as well, [The Winged Scourge](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0278820/combined) from 1943 (which stars the 7 Dwarves) not only features blood graphically and in close-up, [it's practically *about* it](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xyo9rx_the-winged-scourge_kids), since it's an educational short about the danger of mosquitos. Here's a still frame from it with a mosquito drinking blood:

[image]

Comment: There are also possible blood stains on the wall after a shootout in [Alice's Wild West Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgGUQ-HGUb4) from 1924 (around 9:35), but I'm not including it as an answer because 1. it's only partially animated and 2. it's B&W and the black splatters could be other things.

Answer (score 27):

The earliest Disney animated movie I can find is [Sleeping Beauty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053285/?ref_=sr_2), from 1959, which shows the Dragon being slain by a sword, showing some blood. I found this picture, I see no reason why this picture is not genuine...

[image]

In live action movies, in [20,000 Leagues Under The Sea (1954)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046672/), Captain Nemo (played by James Mason) is shot whilst boarding the Nautilus.  He is seen climbing stairs, and there is a big patch of blood on his jacket.

[Youtube hosted copy of the scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=nVk2qGmKQH0#t=435)

Comment: Isn't there suppose to be part in the story where someone pricks their finger on a spindle?

Comment: @MathewFoscarini - good thinking .... but I found this clip of that scene - no blood at all.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuWGgqDKugI

Comment: Darn! They didn't show it. There is suppose to be blood. :)

Comment: not only is iandotkelly correct in identifying that Up is not the first film to feature blood, [its not even the first Pixar Film](http://pixar.wikia.com/Up_Trivia): 'This is the third time blood was shown in a Pixar movie. The first time was in Finding Nemo and next in The Incredibles.'

Answer (score -2):

In Tarzan (1999), where the mother gorilla finds baby Tarzan, there are bloody jaguar footprints on the floor in the Treehouse!

Comment: The 1999 movie?

Answer (score -3):

Hercules, where the cyclops beats him up, Herc bleeds from his mouth.

Comment: Hercules was from 1997.  Sorry to be picky, but we have examples from the 50s.